# clonezilla: "`/home/partimage` is full"

Tags: clonezilla

I'm trying to clone a 480GB SSD to a 3TB drive.  I'm using device-image.  It gets to about %1.7 and tells me that `/home/partimage` is full.  I'm sure I selected /sda2 (the 3tb drive) as home/partimage.  I've tried a couple different options in the advanced wizard with no luck.

The only thing I can think is that these drives are both encrypted with bitlocker.  Is this an issue?  If so, what is the fix? If not, what in the heck is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I know that is a very old question but I found it by googling the error. I had the very same message and in my case the problem was that the harddrive was formatted in FAT32 and max file size was limited to 4Go (See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938432.aspx for details).

So formatting the harddrive in [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) fixe that issue.

Hope this can helps someone else.